# Riemann Sum Example

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

Can someone explain why we divide the different velocities by 1/12.

Comment: Can you see a mention of the number $\frac{1}{12}$ in the solution? Perhaps that can be a hint ...

Comment: 5 minutes is $\frac{1}{12)$ of an hour.

Answer (score 2):

The speed is in miles per hour.  The bins are 5 minutes wide and in a Riemann sum, we multiply the height of a bin by the width of a bin.  5 minutes is one twelfth of an hour...